# Webmin - my emails are going to junk folder

Tags: php, email, spam, webmin, virtualmin

about a week ago i started to learn how to use Webmin, and Virtualmin. I have an own dedicated server at Server4you, but when i'm trying to send email via PHP mail(), or Roundcube, the messages are displaying in the junk folder (gmail, Hotmail, godaddy's mail).

I started to analyze what's wrong with it, updated my DNS Records at cloudflare (added dmarc, and spf Records as well), turned of SSL mode, repaired my headers in PHP mailer, checked for blacklist (all fine), but nothing changed.

Any tips, somebody had same issues?
Thank you for your help in advance! :)

- Mark

Comment: Check your ip against the spam black list s

Comment: @Dagon i already checked it, as i wrote. All fine with it.

Comment: Sorry missed that. There really ara a bizzilon potential possibilities here

Comment: @Dagon yah, i know, that's why i'm asking, if somebody has tips..big community, maybe..:)

Comment: I analyzed my page with mytoolbox, without errors.

Answer (score 1):

Okey, i did it. :)
Under Virtualmin section i enabled Email messages -> DomainKeys Identified Mail, then added domainkey to DNS's TXT record.